# Second instance of Mail.app with different accounts on them and different file locations

Tags: mail.app

is there a way of having the second instance of Mail.app for keeping private and work stuff separately? I found out that many users have similar needs to mine. This will probably mean that all files and settings need to be kept in different folders.

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the app after backing up your system? This will need some details as protections have changed in different versions of macOS. (Assuming your on macOS and not an iPad or iPhone)

Comment: Yes, I'm on macOS. But when I duplicate the app, folders where all files are being kept are the same as the initial one, aren't they? So it won't allow me to create separate settings, separate accounts, etc.

Comment: I won’t mix personal and business on a computer and use different apps when I break my “rule” on portable devices to ensure I have different sandboxes for contacts, calendars and emails (or use webmail for the “other”) so I can’t say if Apple has done the work to fully sandbox mail.app as you are proposing.

Comment: What about files? If you need to keep e-mails separate doesn’t it apply to files as well? Maybe you should set up new user account for work instead of trying to find solution per application.

Comment: A way here is to have two users - one for work and one for personal use - they will share apps but not configuration or data storage